# Using SlimPHP, how can I create clean URLs without %20?

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to create a lightweight PHP application using SlimPHP. I have values in the database with model names of cars and they contain spaces.

Whenever you try to go to a detail page such as `mysite.com/detail/2001/mazda/b2300%20pickup`, it errors.

If you went to a detail page without a space like `mysite.com/detail/2001/mazda/b2300`, it would work fine.

I would like to replace the spaces with dashes.

Here's a screenshot of my error and what I'm showing in the database:

[image]

**Routes:**

```
$app->get('/detail/:year/:make/:model', 'getFull');

function getFull($year, $make, $model) {

$app = new \Slim\Slim(); 
try {
    $db = getConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM towdata WHERE YearMfg = ". $db->quote($year) . "AND Make = ". $db->quote($make) . "AND Model = ". $db->quote($model) . "ORDER BY YearMfg DESC";
    $query = $db->query($sql);
    $result_array = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    $app->render('unit.php', array('all' => $result_array));            
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "error: " . $e;
}
```

}

**Unit.php where I build the URL**

```
<a href=\"/detail/".strtolower($data['YearMfg'])."/".strtolower($data['Make'])."/".strtolower($data['Model'])."\">
```

Thanks for your time and I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Spaces in your URLs, it's the wrong thing to do. Don't pretend to want that, but rather take the spaces out.

Comment: @BrianGottier yes, I know. i would like to replace them with dashes.

Comment: It can be wrong, but I suspect, that with you've search string exactly 'B2300%20Pickup' and your `$result_array` is empty (I didn't use laravel, sry)... may be `urldecode()` for `$year, $make and $model` before use in sql-query can helps...

Comment: Why not just create an alias on your SQL with a REPLACE function to replace the <space> for a -?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use hyphens/dashes instead of spaces you can use PHP's `str_replace`: http://php.net/str_replace

```
echo str_replace(' ', '-', 'honda civic'); // honda-civic
```

Comment: Putting data through `urlencode` is always a good idea but if you put a hyphen through `urlencode` nothing will change. `echo urlencode('-'); // -`